# Is there any way to root Samsung a20e android 10 without pc?

Tags: root-access, usb

I wanted to flash boot.img from magisk but my usb cable killed my pc. Is there any other way to root i/ And if there is any way to do something with that pc? Iys not charging after plugging usb it was okay for 10 seconds and then died.

Comment: do not try to root your device you will brick it for sure. rooting is not a three minutes thing, you need good preparation and should read and understand what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

If you have only 1 USB port in the PC, try a PCIe USB card.

As for rooting with Magisk without a PC, unless you can find a port of TWRP for it, I doubt it.  (There's no official TWRP for the A20, and flashing Magisk requires TWRP as far as I can see from everything TopJohnWu has said.  You can try the one at https://mega.nz/folder/LTZlUKyI#oxxVc5zj8tP4bNQBIo8AlA - no guarantees, and no saying how long it's going to be up there.)

If you get TWRP running, Install (in TWRP) the latest Magisk (not the manager, although you'll need that installed too - as an app) from TWRP.
Running the manager after that should tell you that Magisk is installed.

On second consideration (after thinking for a few minutes), you'll probably need a PC to install TWRP.  So maybe use someone else's PC to install Magisk?  (Then you can just patch a boot.img file [that you can extract from a BL tar] and flash it with Odin.)

Comment: one can't flash TWRP without PC. indeed your edit is the only valid part of your answer. [magisk](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#unlocking-bootloader) official recommended root method is patching whole *AP_\*.tar.md5* file and flash it to AP together with + BL + CP + USERDATA/HOME(CSC) from Odin (TWRP is neither recommended from topjohnwu nor required). one can also flash from heimdall instead (however, boot.img is not in BL and must not flashed to BL)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Samsung devices running Android 7.0+ or later can only rooted with Odin or heimdall. you need a PC for this (or something that can act like PC)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213616 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225021